# Delivery Status for Emails in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, case

Our client want us to get them a delivery status for emails in Salesforce.

We are sending many Salesforce emails to members(Case emails, password
emails etc.)

Does anyone here knows if is it possible to get delivery stats on these emails, like email send time, open rate, clickthrough rate etc.?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can use [**Email Logs**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_monitor_emails_sent_from_salesforce.htm&type=5) to check the delivery status, send datetime and some technical information about the emails sent from Salesforce.

Other than that (more marketing related information) I don't know about it. Maybe you should check Marketing Cloud.

Kr,
Guillermo